# What will happen if multiple proxies are set up for the same class/method

Tags: java, proxy, aop, spring-aop

I need to intercept method invocation in a class that might be already proxied by spring aop. I was thinking about setting up additional proxy. Is there any risk associated with having multiple proxies on the same thing? Is it at all doable? And what would be an alternative approach to intercepting method invocation? Thanks.

Comment: You don't want to proxy a proxy... Unless you want a lot of problems. Why do you need multiple proxies? You can just add the advice to the existing proxy, spring will do this for yu if you just use the Spring AOP approach. Don't try to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I am not trying to reinvent the wheel, I am trying to add some functionality around a method call that I can't modify, without touching existing advice (which might or might not be there). Basically - I am adding functionality to a library, the client using the library uses spring aop on some objects, but I do not have a control over that or know if they use aop on this specific class.

Comment: Just use Spring AOP and Spring will handle it. If you try to hack around yourself you probably end up proxying a proxy with all sorts of strange issues as a result.

Comment: So you say if I use spring aop in my class, add an aspect and a pointcut to a specific method, and then someone else will take that library (checked in from maven) and adds another aspect and a pointcut to the same method, everything will be ok?

Comment: Yes, it will be okay. The worst case could be that you need to set aspect precedence in case it makes a difference in which advice are applied to the same joinpoint, but normally you should be fine. AOP would not be a good concept if it could only take care of one cross-cutting concern. It only makes sense for multiple ones.

Comment: yes, great thanks, I have also just seen in in Spring AOP docs :)